# Как выбрать заданную фразу через регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

"something here mail@mail.com, mail@mail.com, mail@mail.com something here"

В текст могут добавляться как "чистые адреса" так и с примесью фраз - ну например, просят человека просто указать его адрес и он пишет "mail@mail.com", а может написать "мой адрес mail@mail.com" - вот и нужно выдёргивать фразы с "чистыми адресами" без "примеси" побочных фраз.

Как выбрать фразу, содержащую только "mail@mail.com"?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/HxbS54/2)

Это выражение находит все подстроки, начинающиеся с 1 и более символов, отличных от пробелов, потом `@`, потом снова 1 и более символов, отличных от пробелов, точка и снова 1 и более символов, отличных от пробелов. `\b` - граница слова, отсекает пунктуацию.

Если стоит цель найти последнее вхождение адреса электронной почты, добавьте блок предварительного просмотра вперёд:

```
\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b(?!.*\S+@\S+\.\S+\b)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/HxbS54/3)

Comment: запятые захватывает первое демо. и кириллицу не охватывает.

Comment: А тут их нет: *он пишет "mail@mail.com", а может написать "мой адрес mail@mail.com"*. Во-вторых, говорить о кириллице можно только зная используемую библиотеку регулярных выражений/язык программирования.

Comment: фразы с "примесями" должны отфильтровываться вместе с адресами; из указанного примера должна остаться только вторая фраза - под фразами я подразумеваю части строк, разделённые запятой, поправьте с терминологией, если я не правильно выражаюсь

Comment: Т.е. `something here mail@mail.com, mail@mail.com, mail@mail.com something here` -> `mail@mail.com something here`? Добавьте в вопрос Ваш код + тег языка.

Comment: на выходе только "mail@mail.com", без других двух упоминаний; вопрос не привязан к конкретному коду и языку

Comment: А тогда не понятно, каковы критерии. Найти последнее вхождение адреса в строке (при наличии дубликатов)? Кстати, регулярные выражения всегда привязаны к конкретному языку/конкретной их реализации. `\b` может не сработать в некоторых языках и случаях.

Comment: а как можно это решить, если например адрес будет постоянный?

Comment: Найти последнее вхождение адреса в строке (при наличии дубликатов)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50445/discussion-between-titov-andrei-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это: `(^|,)\s*([\w_\.-]+?@[\w_\.-]+?)\s*(,|$)`

```
puts <<EOT.match(/(^|,)\s*([\w_\.-]+?@[\w_\.-]+?)\s*(,|$)/)[2]
  something here mail@mail_1.com, mail@mail_2.com, ,,
  mail@mail_3.com something here mail@mail_4.com"
EOT
```

[На ideone](http://ideone.com/fTt2o1).

Comment: цепляет пробел и запятые - https://regex101.com/r/BmH4t3/1

Comment: Немного исправил и закинул тест на ideone на Ruby

Comment: так исходник изменили, добавили 1-4 к mail - изначально они все идентичны

Comment: Это сделал специально - чтобы показалось то, что нашлось. Если вернуть обратно найдется `mail@mail.com`. Только если они одинаковые, как вы поймете - какое словилось?